# Getting results with the correct time zone shift (Postgresql, Django)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timezone-offset

In my project (Django, using Postgresql) I need to display statistics on the number of registered users by day. In the database, all time fields are stored with the UTC zone. In settings.py parameters set:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

Code in a view that returns this stitistic:
(date1 & date2 parameters are obtained from a request)

```
self.queryset = User.objects

if date1 and date2:
    self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(
        created_at__range=(date1, date2.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59))
    )
self.queryset = self.queryset \
            .extra({'day': "date(created_at)"}) \
            .values("day") \
            .annotate(
                count=Count("id"),
                site_count=Count("id", filter=Q(account_type=User.TYPE_WEBSITE)),
                bot_count=Count("id", filter=Q(account_type=User.TYPE_TELEGRAM)),
            ) \
            .order_by('day')

return Response({
    "new_users": self.queryset
})
```

Unfortunately, if I specify date parameters both '2021-05-11', then the "wrong" answer will be formed:

```
"new_users": [
        {
            "day": "2021-05-10",
            "count": 2,
            "site_count": 1,
            "bot_count": 1
        },
        {
            "day": "2021-05-11",
            "count": 4,
            "site_count": 2,
            "bot_count": 2
        }
    ],
```

We see the two days instead of one.
The following SQL is generated by Django:

```
SELECT (date(created_at)) AS "day", COUNT("authentication_user"."id") AS "count",
COUNT("authentication_user"."id") FILTER 
(WHERE "authentication_user"."account_type" = 'Website') AS "site_count", COUNT("authentication_user"."id") FILTER 
(WHERE "authentication_user"."account_type" = 'Telegram') AS "bot_count" 
FROM "authentication_user" WHERE "authentication_user"."created_at" BETWEEN '2021-05-11 00:00:00+03:00' AND '2021-05-11 23:59:59+03:00' 
GROUP BY (date(created_at) ) ORDER BY "day" ASC
```

I experimented and made select queries manually:

```
SELECT * from authentication_user WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-14 00:00:00+03:00' AND '2021-06-14 23:59:59+03:00'
```

As a result of this request, a correct result is generated, but it is generated in the UTC time zone. I see a lot of records with creation dates between 2021-06-13 21:00 and 2021-06-14 21:00.
I can see that the initial query also produces the correct answer, but due to the fact that each resulting date in the UTC zone, the
`SELECT (date (created_at)) AS "day"` 
creates a split into two days.

Please tell me how I can get postgresql to form a date-based split of results based on my time zone.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
SELECT date(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow') AS "day", COUNT("authentication_user"."id") AS "count", COUNT("authentication_user"."id") FILTER (WHERE "authentication_user"."account_type" = 'Website') AS "site_count", COUNT("authentication_user"."id") FILTER (WHERE "authentication_user"."account_type" = 'Telegram') AS "bot_count" FROM "authentication_user" WHERE "authentication_user"."created_at" BETWEEN '2021-06-14 00:00:00+03:00' AND '2021-06-14 23:59:59+03:00' GROUP BY date(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow') ORDER BY "day" ASC
```

python:

```
self.queryset = self.queryset \
            .extra({'day': "date(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow')"}) \
            .values("day") \
            .annotate(
                count=Count("id"),
                site_count=Count("id", filter=Q(account_type=User.TYPE_WEBSITE)),
                bot_count=Count("id", filter=Q(account_type=User.TYPE_TELEGRAM)),
            ) \
            .order_by('day')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did works, but it's not ideal. The django docs recommend you use `extra()` only as a last resort, because this tool will be deprecated:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Instead, to make your application more flexible and avoid dropping down to raw SQL unnecessarily, use `activate()` to set the timezone for a given query:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate